# java integer array convert to ascii and put into char array

Tags: java, c, arrays

here is question
Write a method that generates an int array as a parameter, converts
the generated integers into characters and print the new char array.
Array values should be in the range [0 -255].

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] array1 = new char [100];
    int d;
    int[] array = getArray();
    convert(array,array1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.print(array1[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static int convert(int[] array, char[] array1) {
    for (int a=0;a<100;a++) {
        array [a] = toChars(array1[a]);
    }
}

public static int[] getArray() {
    int[] array = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
    }
    System.out.println();
    return array;
}
```

I have encountered few problem with that. I could not convert integer to ASCII code. What I can use instead of:

```
for (int a=0;a<100;a++) {
    array [a] = toChars(array1[a]);
}
```

Comment: What does this has to do with the C programming language?

Comment: is this jni related? toChars() ?

Comment: Oh, and you mix up the integer and character arrays. Proper variable naming would have shown that (plus you probably have some compiler errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void convert(int[] array, char[] array1) {
    int length = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // this converts a integer into a character
        array1[i] = (char) array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your convert method should be:

```
public static void convert(int[] array, char[] array1) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
        array1[a] = (char) array[a];
    }
}
```

Just type cast int to char.